# How to compare words dictionary size (aba < ada) of a string, using pointers only

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

I'm in the first year, currently studying "C".
It's the first task I'm actually hitting a wall, the task is:

"Create a function, that receives a pointer of a string, and a pointer of the string's size. The string itself contains a sentence. The function will return a pointer to the beginning of the biggest dictionary sized word (aba < ada) and the value of the words length using the size pointer."
* you cannot use operators [] and indexes, do this task using pointers only!

Example: for the sentence "aba ada aaa" the function will return "ada" which will later be printed by main.

I feel a bit hard stuck, I understand I need to run through the whole string, using at least 2 pointers(?) I need to keep comparing them and ditch the small one until eventually, I have the biggest word and its size. but can't seem to find a way to do so.

I wrote a super long code before that, which didn't really work and it seems to me that I miss something crucial and that this code doesn't have to be long.

```
int findHighest(char *ptr, int *size)
{
   int nSize = 0, nSize1 = 0;    
   char *ptr3;

   for (char *ptr1 = ptr; *ptr1 != '\0'; ptr1++)
   {
      for (char *ptr2 = ptr1; (*ptr2 != ' ') && (*ptr2 != '\0') ; ptr2++)
      {
          nSize++;
          ptr3 = ptr2;
          nSize1 = nSize;
      }
   }
}
void main()
{
   char sentence[100] = { 0 };
   printf("enter your sentence:\n");
   gets(sentence);
   char sentence2[100];
   int size;
   strcpy(sentence2, findHighest(sentence, &size));
   sentence2[size] = '\0';
   printf("the biggest word is:'%s'\n", sentence2);
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Lets start by actually returning something from that `findHighest` function. You promised you would with the declared `char` result, but never bothered to actually do so. Secondly `strcpy` doesn't take  `char` for either argument, so that's clearly wrong too.

Comment: ... and, of course, the problem description says the function is supposed to return a pointer, not an individual `char`, so how about fixing that before figuring out *what* pointer to return.

Comment: Got you, but i dont know what i shall return and when, I mean if i assume the sentence contains only 3 words i mean I can probably do it, but if its longer? i cant seem to understand how to keep playing with the pointers through the whole sentence comparing all the words in it and returning the right one.

And excuse me for my ignorance but couldn't understand the comment regarding     strcpy     .

Comment: Is the problem translated from another language?  The wording "biggest dictionary sized word" is not at all idiomatic in English for what it appears to be intended to mean.  I myself would say something more like "last in dictionary order", or even "lexicographically greatest".

Comment: yes it is. did the best i could translating it :S

Comment: `size` is not used in `findHighest(char *ptr, int *size)`, so the calling code `findHighest(sentence, &size)` does not affect `main()`'s `size`.  Then `sentence2[size]` is _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing an analogous task with integers, how would it look?  Something like this:

```
// With ints instead of (sub)strings:
int findHighest(int ints[], int *size) {
    int greatest = ints[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < *size; i++) {
        if (ints[i] > greatest) greatest = ints[i];
    }

    return greatest;
}
```

That's a perfectly good model for your actual problem.  The issues are how to adapt something like that to deal with the differences in the type and form of input, with the constraint that you must avoid using indexing, and with the requirement to return the length of the largest string.

But before we go on, let's deal with an issue that may be confusing you.  As translated, the problem says "The function will return a pointer to the beginning" of the greatest word, whereas in the example, you say "the function will return 'ada'".  In the first place, no, the function could not ever return `"ada"` itself, because that's an *array*, and you cannot return arrays in C.  But more importantly, as I read the problem, your function is to return a pointer to the start of the "ada" substring *in the input string*.  In your example, if you printed that with, say, `puts()` then you would see `ada aaa`.

So how to proceed?  Let's start with the right function signature:

```
char *findHighest(char *string, int *size) {
```

Let's next observe that as long as the input does not contain leading whitespace, the start of the first word is the same as the start of the sentence:

```
    char *greatest = string;
```

Now, you need to find the start of the next word, and the length of the current word should come easily out of that, too.  Given a pointer to the next word, you can compare the two words via `strcmp()`, provided you're willing to assume that the spaces between words are lexicographically less than all letters appearing in your words.  That is indeed the case for all ASCII-compatible single-byte encodings, and also for UTF-8: all characters less than `' '` are control characters.  If you want to be even safer, however, then you can use `strncmp()` instead, taking the word lengths into account.

As you go through the string, you'll need to track not just the pointer to the so-far greatest word, but also its length.  Then at the end, you simply

```
    *size = length_of_greatest;
    return greatest;
}
```

This being an academic exercise, I leave the remaining details to you to work out.